# Flexbox in react native : How to align 2 items at the center of the screen?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, position

I discovered flexbox recently and I'm struggling to make it work, I'm surely missed some concept that make me hard time to understands it's mechanics so here is what I have:

It's a preview camera screen

- with a back button on the top right
- A text in the middle
- and a record button to shoot some images

Here is what I have at the moment:

[image]

this is done with this React native component (style included)

```
import React from "react";
import { RNCamera } from "react-native-camera";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View, Platform} from "react-native";
import {Icon, Text} from "native-base";
import RequestPermissions from "../components/Permissions/RequestPermissions";
import I18n from "../i18n/i18n";

/**
 * This is the component which allows the user to film his own film
 */
export default class CameraScreen extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.camera = null;
  }

  state = {
    isRecording: false,
    iconVid: "record",
    iconMode: null,
    overlay: true
  };

  /**
   * With RNCamera, it seems that permission is always asked to the user... Maybe this code is then irrelevant
   */
  componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      RequestPermissions().then(() => {
        console.log("granted");
      }).then((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.stopRecording();
  };

  stopRecording = () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      this.camera.stopRecording();
      this.setState({
        isRecording: false,
        iconVid: "record"
      });
    }
  };

  renderCamera = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          ref={cam => {
            this.camera = cam;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
        >
          <View style={styles.controlsContainer}>
            <View style={styles.topRightButton}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                <Icon name={"arrow-left"} type={"Feather"} style={styles.iconFurtive}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.middleContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.actionText}>{I18n.t("action_text").toUpperCase()}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.recordVideo()}>
                <Icon name={this.state.iconVid} type={"MaterialCommunityIcons"} style={styles.iconCamera}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </RNCamera>
      </View>
    );
  };

  /**
   * For more options
   * https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md#recordasyncoptions-promise
   */
  recordVideo = () => {
    if (this.camera) {
        this.setState({ isRecording: true, iconVid: "stop" });
        // Show the overlay
        console.log("Device is Recording");
        this.camera.recordAsync({maxDuration: 15}).then(data => {
            this.stopRecording();

            console.log("Stop Recording");
            console.log(data);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          this.stopRecording();
        });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return this.renderCamera()
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:30,
  },
  controlsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  topRightButton: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  middleContainer: {
    flex: 0.5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  leftContainer: {
    flex: 0.5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
  actionText: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 72
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  iconCamera: {
    color: "#ff4459",
    marginBottom: 50,
    padding: 25,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
  iconFurtive: {
    color: "#fff",
    marginTop: 50,
    marginLeft: 50,
  }
});
```

Here is what I want:

[image]

How to do that with flexbox? What am I missing?

Comment: use **position** here https://unbug.gitbooks.io/react-native-training/content/32_absolute_&_relative.html

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh absolute position is not a solution for me, because portrait or landscape, i need the same disposition of those element, only flex can provide this easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code changed at View with {styles.topRightButton}

```
return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <RNCamera
              ref={cam => {
                this.camera = cam;
              }}
              style={styles.preview}
            >
              <View style={styles.controlsContainer}>
                <View style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start',}}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                    <Icon name={"arrow-left"} type={"Feather"} style={styles.iconFurtive}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>
                  <View style ={{height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'transparent'}} />
                  <Text style={styles.actionText}>{I18n.t("action_text").toUpperCase()}</Text>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.recordVideo()}>
                    <Icon name={this.state.iconVid} type={"MaterialCommunityIcons"}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            </RNCamera>
          </View>
        );
```

Comment: sorry, this is not working, all components are now on top row, do you have a codesandbox sample to show  see how your solution may work ?

Comment: Check this out once https://codesandbox.io/embed/xpqr29218p. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah it's something like that, can you provide an explanation please about what I've missed in my flexbox comprehension ? It seems I was some close to the solution but can't achieve it. I'd like to understand how flex is working with cild components, any help would be appreciated to make this answer accepted

Comment: Using flex, we can arrange items vertically or horizontally. So divide your views in that way(the back button and (action and camera click) are vertical). action and camera are horizontal.

Comment: I saw your empty View bloc how can have the same result without it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179322/discussion-between-kranthi-and-hooli).

Answer (score 1):

For middle and left the content should be in the same div with that div having a flexDrirection: 'row'. This puts them in the same row.

The controls container can have justifyContent: 'center', and alignItems: 'center'.

The topRightButton should override the parents style.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, can you please provide a code sandbox or something because i tried and no changes :s

Comment: In fact something changed, whole elements are in the center -> column